# I want to replicate the same SAS in R, appreciate your inputs

Tags: r

I need an equivalent statement in R:

```
if fipscode in (21015,21037,21117) then do;
   number = 150;
   name = "CINCINNATI SO";
end;
```

Comment: Not sure why this is flagged as too broad.  It looks like a very clear question that has been given a very clear answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
ind <- data$fipscode %in% c(21015,21037,21117)
data$number[ind] <- 150
data$name[ind]   <- "CINCINNATI SO"
```